# How to map a sequence of keys to <dead_greek>?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, xinput, compose-key, setxkbmap

I have mapped <kbd>Insert</kbd> to <kbd>Multi_key</kbd> (also known as <kbd>Compose</kbd>) so I can input ä or µ. I've used `xmodmap -e 'keycode 118 = Multi_key'` in my wm init script.

Now, checking `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, I see there are already rules to input Greek letters:

```
...
<dead_grave> <nobreakspace>           : "̀"   U0300      # COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
<dead_greek> <A>            : "Α"   U0391    # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA
<dead_greek> <a>            : "α"   U03B1    # GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
<dead_greek> <B>            : "Β"   U0392    # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA
<dead_greek> <b>            : "β"   U03B2    # GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA
<dead_greek> <D>            : "Δ"   U0394    # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA
<dead_greek> <d>            : "δ"   U03B4    # GREEK SMALL LETTER DELTA
...
```

Problem is, the <kbd>dead_greek</kbd> key does not exist in my layout.
I can either use `xmodmap -e 'keycode 118 = dead_greek'` to map <kbd>Insert</kbd> to it, losing <kbd>Multi key</kbd> **or** I can just somehow use the sequence <kbd>Multi key</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> to register as <kbd>Dead Greek</kbd> (losing characters like ğ or ġ, which I'm OK about).

How can I do the latter preferably with one line commands to put in my wm init script?

Note that I do **not** want to mutate `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` or create a `~/.XCompose` and add all the Greek letter definitions *again* (since they already exist in the system Compose file)

In short, how to <kbd>Multi_key</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>→<kbd>dead_greek</kbd>?

**update**
For a temporary workaround, based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/24930/172587), I was able to map <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to <kbd>dead_greek</kbd>.
`xmodmap -e "keycode 118 shift = Multi_key dead_greek"`

Weirdly, none of the modifiers listed via `xmodmap -pm` are usable here except shift, so this was a compromise…

Comment: For me the least painful solution was to repeat the definitions in the `~/.XCompose`. I know you said you don't want that, but it does have the advantage that it works on Wayland.